# What is the purpose of this approach to access modifiers?

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

Consider the following code:

```
    private string _text = null;
    private string[] _values = null;

    public string Text { get { return _text; } }
    public string[] Values { get { return _values; } }
```

What does this accomplish that having the public members alone would not?

Comment: Note that you should be *very, very careful* when exposing an array as a read-only property of a class.  **The array reference is read only but the array contents are not.** The user of this class can mutate the contents of the array at will. If that is not desirable then instead return a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>`, not a `string[]`.

Comment: Eric's detailed thoughts on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using properties instead of public fields, you hide the implementation.

If at some point you need to change what the Text and Values properties return, you can change the behavior without changing the API of the class.

Additionally, this idiom limits external access to the exposed data as read-only.

Comment: Rephrased the matter of read-only access, hope that this is less ambiguous. Thanks to @AdamHouldsworth!

Answer (score 6):

It's to make values readonly, though I'd be more inclined to write it like this:

```
public string Text { get; private set;}
public string[] Values { get; private set; }
```

Comment: This would only make the values read only to stuff outside the class.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I do not disagree.

Comment: Just clarifying because throwing words like readonly around could be confused with the `readonly` keyword.

Comment: Further, you can better control the access (validation) and implement some more advanced things like `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Be careful! `Values` is "read only" so that `_values` can not be overwritten, but it is perfectly legitimate to write `Values[i] = something` and now the contents of the array as changes. So, it does not "make values readonly" except for very special definitions of "readonly."

Comment: @Jason Yep, it really should be IEnumerable<string> instead of string[] when it's exposed like that.

Answer (score 5):

This code would allow external entities to read your values, while your code internally could modify the backing field.

You can short-hand that using auto-properties:

```
public string Text { get; private set; }
public string[] Values { get; private set; }
```

With a public field, you would not be able to protect against external modification and support internal modification at the same time.

Even if you want to expose a field as writeable externally, I would still suggest encapsulating the thing in a property - you never know if you need to support something internally without breaking the external contract (custom code in the set/get gives you space to do this).

Not to mention most data binding frameworks do not see fields, only properties.

Answer (score 2):

The `_text` and `_values` can only be set within the class that they are defined, but their values can be accessed via the properties.

Answer (score 2):

In your example its making the properties as read only, but there are other uses as well.

```
public string Text { get { return _text; } }
```

If you want to do some operation internally on the `return_text` and then return it against proeperty `Text` you could something like.

```
public string Text { get { return _text.ToUpper(); } }
```

This is field [Encapsulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)

> Encapsulation is sometimes referred to as the first pillar or
>   principle of object-oriented programming. According to the principle
>   of encapsulation, a class or struct can specify how accessible each of
>   its members is to code outside of the class or struct. Methods and
>   variables that are not intended to be used from outside of the class
>   or assembly can be hidden to limit the potential for coding errors or
>   malicious exploits.

Consider the following example:

```
// private field
    private DateTime date;


    // Public property exposes date field safely.
    public DateTime Date 
    {
        get 
        {
            return date;
        }
        set 
        {
            // Set some reasonable boundaries for likely birth dates.
            if (value.Year > 1900 && value.Year <= DateTime.Today.Year)
            {
                date = value;
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

    }
```

In this example there is a private field `date` which is exposed publicly through property `Date`. Now if you want to set the boundary for date then you can see the set part of the property.